# Changing the value of HtmlHelpers.ValidationSummaryCssClassName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

Yes, it's a bit ass-about-face, but what's the best way to change the css class name output for validation errors, across a project?

The source is available here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528#266468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't its a readonly value.

You just have to style the elements created with those css names.